How optimize smooth blue using tailwind css?
I am currently developing a website that adds two div and blur effect of 10rem. Now all works fine, but blur effect is not smooth.

<div>
    <div className='w-[25rem] h-[25rem] bg-[#64403b] rounded-full blur-[10rem] absolute top-17 left-[50rem]'></div>
    <div className='w-[25rem] h-[25rem] bg-[#422277] rounded-full blur-[10rem] absolute top-17 left-[30rem]'></div>
</div>

how to remove those circles and smooth the blur?

How so? On which browser? It looks OK to me on Edge. Apart from being very dark.

FYI, I can just about see the so called "circles" when I set my monitor to maximum brightness (in firefox and chrome). I guess that's just normal. Do you know/have an example of some website that does that better ? - In the posted image I can see the circles already on a somewhat medium/high brightness, but that's only the image, which might use less colors than the monitor.

It can be done if you carefully add some dither noise so that the contour edges are disrupted. The eye is very good at spotting faint edge transitions on some colours. You can see it on TVs too when there are smooth colour gradients - most often in dark blue skies.
